# Error occurred in "OPSS Processing" phase execution

Tags: oracle, window

I am trying to install oracle database 19c client in the windows server 2016. However I am encountered with the following error

```
CFGFWK-64254: Error occurred in "OPSS Processing" phase execution
```

Answer (score 0):

Oracle database 19c client installation might failed because of the operating system's password policy. The provided password for the "oracle" user does not comply the password policy of the Operating System. Please provide a password for the "oracle" user that meets the password policy requirements as per your operating system.